# Why is nested form returning a compile error in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, form-helpers

I have two models: newsavedmap and waypoints.

My newsavedmap:

```
    class Newsavedmap < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :waypoints, :dependent => :destroy
        accepts_nested_attributes_for :waypoints
    end
```

The form, which lives on maptry.html.erb

```
    <% form_for @newsavedmap, :html=>{:id=>'createaMap'} do |f| %>
<%= f.error_messages %>
<%= f.text_field :name, {:id=>"savemap_name", :size=>30, :value=>"New Map"}%></p>

     <%= f.fields_for :waypoints do |p| %>
    <%= p.select :waypoint, itinerary.locations_for_select,{},{ :multiple=>"true", :id=>"waypoints", :class=>"mobile-waypoints-remove"}%>   
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

For some reason, this is throwing the following error:

```
    ActionView::TemplateError (compile error .../maptry.html.erb:392: syntax error, unexpected ')'        
    ...ields_for :waypoints do |p| ).to_s); @output_buffer.concat ...
```

Thanks for any help you can offer!

**FINAL WORKING VERSION FOR RAILS 2**

```
    <% f.fields_for @waypoints do |p| %>
    <%= p.select :waypoint, {},{}, :multiple=>"true", :id=>"waypoints", :class=>"mobile-waypoints-remove" %>      
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are ending you form_for before starting the nested form

Try the below code

```
<% form_for @newsavedmap, :html=>{:id=>'createaMap'} do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, {:id=>"savemap_name", :size=>30, :value=>"New Map"}%></p>


<%= f.fields_for :waypoints do |p| %>
    <%= p.select :waypoint, itinerary.locations_for_select,{},{ :multiple=>"true", :id=>"waypoints", :class=>"mobile-waypoints-remove"}%>   
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Raghu, thanks so much for your response. Unfortunately, that was just a typo as I cut a lot of the unnecessary code from the form. The repaired version is above, still throwing the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: can you tell me which is line number 392 from the code which you pasted above?

Comment: Try <%= form_for @newsavedmap, :html=>{:id=>'createaMap'} do |f| %> . I see the = sign is missing on form_for

Comment: When I delete the lines from `<% f.fields_for :waypoints do |p| %>` all the way to <% end %>` no error appears, so I'm not sure it's the = sign. Will try, though.

Comment: In Rails 2. Does that matter?

Comment: try commenting only the select tag keeping the nested form intact. just want to make sure that the select tag syntax is right

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36567/discussion-between-kdp-and-raghu)

Comment: In rails 2 , i think the syntax is a bit different http://apidock.com/rails/v2.0.0/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for .. Try modifying your code as per this link. You have to use a wapypoint object that needs to be passed to fields_for

Comment: I was able to use the information in that link to edit my form field for Rails 2. Working version included above. Thanks! I have a related question if you want to take a crack at it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18523486/how-do-i-convert-this-dropdown-to-a-f-select-in-rails