# Why can't I add a value to a Rails hidden field using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, hidden-field

Thanks for your help with this one. The goal is to put some data from a selected option from a drop-down into a hidden field as the value. I've tested the basic idea outside of Rails with HTML (see a revised fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/e6zZB/1/) and it works. It's only when I go to the Rails hidden field that the value doesn't seem to change. My way of testing is to select an option in the dropdown and then check the source to see if the value has been updated (not sure if that's a good way, though!) FYI, this is Rails 2 (it's an older project).

**jQuery**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#startdrop").change(function () {
          var startidval = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
          $("#start-masterlocation-id-field").val($(startidval).data("data-masterlocation-id"));
        });
    });
```

**Rails dropdown in view**

```
    <select id="startdrop" name="startthere">
<% for location in @itinerary.locations %>
<option data-masterlocation-name="<%= location.masterlocation.name %>" data-masterlocation-id="<%= location.masterlocation.id %>" value="<%= location.masterlocation.street_address %>, <%= location.masterlocation.city %>, <%= location.masterlocation.state %>, <%= location.masterlocation.zip %>"><%= location.masterlocation.name %></option>
<% end %>
</select>
```

**Rails hidden field in view**

```
    <%= hidden_field :newsavedmap, :start_masterlocation_id, :id => "start-masterlocation-id-field" %>
```

**Final Works**

```
    $("#startdrop").change(function () {
        var startidval = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-masterlocation-id');
        $("#start-masterlocation-id-field").val(startidval);
});
```

Comment: what do you see in the view source of the page when you wrote the select box and the hidden field in rails format?

Comment: also please use the rails select_tag to create the options along with the select box

Comment: `<input id="start-masterlocation-id-field" name="newsavedmap[start_masterlocation_id]" type="hidden" />` is the view source result. As to the "select_tag", I'd love to, but I'm getting errors (please see this question I've got on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18523486/how-do-i-convert-this-dropdown-to-a-f-select-in-rails )

Comment: Are you sure that `<%= hidden_field :newsavedmap, :start_masterlocation_id, :id => "start-masterlocation-id-field" %>` is rendering a hidden field with the id `start-masterlocation-id-field`, maybe show the rendered html source

Comment: Hi, house9. Isn't the code I provided in the above comment the rendered html source?

Comment: Try `$("#ddl").change(function () {
    var sd = $(this).find('option:selected').data("startDate");
    alert(sd)
    $("#start2").val(sd);
});
`

Comment: Thanks, Arun, but this code does not create the value. I converted it to fit my view: `$("#startdrop").change(function () {
     var startidval = $(this).find('option:selected').data("startidval");
     $("#start-masterlocation-id-field").val("startidval");
   });`

Comment: no, that is the mark up in your erb view template - when you view source in the browser what mark up is rendered for the hidden field?

Comment: Isn't it `<input id="start-masterlocation-id-field" name="newsavedmap[start_masterlocation_id]" type="hidden" />` ?

Comment: Are you viewing source via the right-click menu in your browser? You should be using either Firebug (for FireFox) or web inspector (for Chrome or Safari) for this. Once the page is loaded the source, as displayed by the browser, isn't ever changed so it will throw you off.

Comment: Whoops. Yes, pdobb, I was viewing the source with right-click rather than using Firebug. I also had to tweak the javascript a little to make it work with my current setup. Glad to offer credit if you want to post the answer (that source code doesn't always show these javascript changes.)